Why do we need dedicated nodes for running a batch job through Data Factory
I came across the below tutorial on Microsoft learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory
It was very helpful to be able to run a python script successfully on ADF and process and persist data on the SQL db.
However, i'm curious as to why we need dedicated nodes for this? Can I not specify an auto-scale formula instead? I am concerned about the cost implications by having a dedicate node/s.


Can I not specify an auto-scale formula instead?

Yes, you can specify auto-scale while pool creation.
You need to consider few things before you select any of the above options.

First analyze your execution of the custom activity and check if your workload is same or not in all executions.
If your workload and execution time are not varying, then selecting dedicated nodes will not impact the cost complications as it will give guaranteed compute power in all cases.
If it varies, then opting for the auto-scale might be the better option as it can reduce/increase the number of nodes as per your workload which can reduce the cost.

